# Light absorbs and Color

Tags: photons, reflection, absorption

I'm curious about how the material absorb the light and reflect the light back as colors in a sense of Quantum Mechanics (Quantum Electro Dynamics)
Does Hadron related to the absorbs of photon ? or are there any other factors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For visible light, it is not a hadron that is absorbing the light.  The energy levels of electrons in atoms and molecules are quantized.  The photon causes an electron to transition from one [atomic orbital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) to a higher energy orbital, or from one [molecular orbital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital) to a higher energy orbital.

Another way matter can absorb light is through [plasmon resonance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_plasmon_resonance).

Answer (score 1):

In the visible spectrum, the hadrons (protons and neutrons in the nuclei) play very little role. They just establish a potential well that captures electrons.

In atoms, the electrons have definite energy levels because they are bound to a nucleus. Light is absorbed when an electrons is promoted from one level to another.

Molecules are much the same, but there can be more levels. Also when atoms are bound to each other, there are vibrational states that can be excited by light.